Hitting objects on the field of play Cricket
A fielder throws the ball at the stumps in an attempt to run out a batsman. The ball hits a plastic water bottle placed behind the stumps of the batsman on strike and with minimal deflection it is fielded by the fielder backing up. He breaks the wicket and the striker is out of his crease by a significant margin. Should the batsman be given out?

Any object placed on the field of play by the fielding side could be deemed to be interfering with play.  When fielding sides first started to place protective helmets behind the stumps when not being worn, to save the time of running them to and from the pavilion, the Laws were changed.
If the ball hits such an object, including a water bottle, the ball is dead.  The batsman is awarded five runs as penalty for the object being there.  The obstruction could have prevented overthrows.
The ball is then treated like a boundary.  The batsmen return to their original ends.
So, no, he cannot be given out.
